# How to make an appChooser in Android

Tags: java, android

I have correctly set everything up, however The implicit activity is not displaying the app chooser, it is saying no apps can carry out this action (The url is what I am wanting to be opened by an app of the user's choosing)

Here is my xml file for MyBrowser:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Here is the code creating the intent and initalizing the appChooser:

```
private void startImplicitActivation() {

    Log.i(TAG, "Entered startImplicitActivation()");

    // TODO - Create a base intent for viewing a URL 
    // (HINT:  second parameter uses parse() from the Uri class)
    Intent viewer = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(URL));


    // TODO - Create a chooser intent, for choosing which Activity
    // will carry out the baseIntent. Store the Intent in the 
    // chooserIntent variable below. HINT: using the Intent class' 
    // createChooser())
    Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(viewer, CHOOSER_TEXT);

    Log.i(TAG,"Chooser Intent Action:" + chooserIntent.getAction());
    // TODO - Start the chooser Activity, using the chooser intent
    startActivity(chooserIntent);

}
```

I am rather baffled because the code looks clear as day to me but I cannot for the life of me figure out why it is not working.

Comment: I think the chooser will forward the Intent directly, if there is only one app to handle it.

Comment: Well I am trying to have it use Android's default browser and MyBrowser as the choices because it is a website address.

Answer (score 0):

For a browser, you use this intent filter (you add intent filter tag): 
       intent-filter

> ```
>  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"
>  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
>  <data android:scheme="http"/>
> ```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you installed the MyBrowser app to the device? If that wasn't installed, it clearly won't work. Aside from that, I'm not sure you need the `<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />` part to your filter. Usually you only need one category, two seems like overkill...

Comment: I have since solved this. I did not have myBrowser installed...lol. Also, <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> is there to indicate to start it implicitly.